# Can I set a creme brulee with agar agar?

Tags: gelling-agents, creme-brulee

I am trying to make a new dish, I really want to make a creme brulee but I don't want to be shackled to the idea of using a ramekin. Is there any way I can set it with agar in a rubber mold and be able to remove it for placing?

Answer (score 4):

Removing a custard (which is what creme brulee) is from its form or mold does not definitely require agar agar.   Flan, which is famous from a number of cuisines, is an unmolded custard.

While experimentation would be required, it is highly likely that if you use a silicone based flexible form, and make a fairly stiff custard, you will be able to gently and carefully unmold it.  You may wish to lightly grease the form before baking the custard to help facilitate release.  [This Chest of Books article](http://chestofbooks.com/food/household/A-Manual-Of-Home-Making/Custards.html) recommends two eggs per cup if milk for a custard that requires unmolding.

Many molded custard recipes exist, although a good number of them have gelatin as an additional stabilizing ingredient.  You may wish to google "molded custard recipe" or "Charlotte recipe" for inspiration (Charlottes tend to have a lady finger garnish around the edges).

If you are interested in using agar agar or other modernist hydro-colloids in your recipe development, you may wish to read the [excellent primer](http://www.cookingissues.com/primers/hydrocolloids-primer/) at Cooking Issues.

Note that they characterize the texture of agar agar gels as somewhat brittle, which may not be ideal for your application.

See also [Can I substitute agar agar for gelatin in pudding](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16804/can-i-substitute-agar-agar-for-gelatin-in-pudding) which is a very similar application.  [Michael at Herbivoracious](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/1393/michael-at-herbivoracious) indicates that agar agar may not be suitable due to the texture.  There are some alternate ideas there that may help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

SAJ14SAJ has a great answer.  Creme Brulee is very similar to Creme Caramel which is a molded custard.

You could try Brulee-ing the unmolded creme caramel, either the top or making a complete shell.  Agar shouldn't be necessary.  Sprinkle the outside with super fine sugar (not icing sugar) and use a plumber's torch.  It could turn out to be an awesome creation!