# Do gums have any nutritional value?

Tags: food-safety, thickening, emulsion, xanthan

Do gums (e.g., [xanthan, guar, cellulose, glucomannan](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/68136/42013)) have any nutritional value, or do they pass undigested [like chewing gum does](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-chewing-gum-takes-seven-years-to-digest/)?

Are there known allergies to any gums?

Answer (score -1):

Gums are considered fibre because they are ignored by our microbiome.

Besides, industry (at the contents of any product that we buy) also consideres fibre anything that is not processed by our digestion.