# What is the Function of Gelatine

Tags: gelatin

I have a recipe that calls for leaf gelatine but I have none. What does gelatine do in a recipe?

Comment: Hello johnc, and welcome to our site! We function differently from classic discussion boards, and we insist on only answering each question once, so people can easily find information in once place instead of hunting for it between dozens of threads. Half of your question has been answered here before, so I removed it - see for answers http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/725. The other part is fine, although it would be much easier to answer if you said what the recipe is. Gelatine is more of an exception, but most ingredients in cooking have different functions depending on recipe.

Comment: what recipe are you doing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on how much of it you're using.

If it's only a small amount, it might be for mouthfeel -- it'll make the liquid more viscous and less 'watery'.  Consider a good chicken soup, where the broth has a bit of body to it.

If it's a large amount, it's to get the liquid to set up.  In something like a panna cotta, aspics, mousse, or a no-bake pie, it's to get the liquid to firm up and become either solid or at least scoopable.

And gelatin doesn't need to be used in solely liquid dishes -- America's Test Kitchen used in a meatloaf recipe for what was most likely mouthfeel.

... but it's possible that there are other uses.  I seem to recall hearing that it can be used to clarify broths as well.

Comment: Thanks all who answered for both the advice and the info on using the site. My recipe is for a no bake cheese cake using philly and sugar, so from the answers I would guess it is it firm it up a bit after the sugar has loosened the philly.

Comment: In the ATK meatloaf recipe, it was (as you suspect) to give the impression of greater moisture in the final product without increasing the fat content of the meat, avoiding a greasy meatloaf.